# Send data with POST-request wont work in Django with AJAX

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, ajax

*First of all: I know, there are a few solutions for this online, but they wont work for me (because they use e.g. Jason or are just outdated)*

I work on a project in Django and want to use ajax for one task:

I want to pass data, after it was processed by ajax, from my template file to my views file (with a POST request), to again make it visible in my templates file.

*Templates-file --> Proccessed data --> POST-request --> views.py --> Template-file*

But it just wont work for me.

My **HTML-Templates-File**:

```
...

<script type="text/javascript">

    var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "/save",
        data: {
            'value': inputDataArray  //I have already defined "inputDataArray" before
        },
        success: function (res, status) {
            alert(res);
            alert(status);
        },
        error: function (res) {
            alert(res.status);                                                                                                                          
        }
    });
</script>
```

My **views.py** file:

```
def save(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request_getdata = request.POST.get("value", None) 
    return render(request, "response.html", {"data":request_getdata})
```

**urls.py** file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index , name='index'),
    path('save', views.save , name='save'),]
```

So I try display it at "**response.html**"...

```
{{data}}
```

...but it just will reload the current page and does not pass any data to the response.html-file.

Does anyone knows what my error is here?

Thanks a lot in advance

P.S.: This is my project structure:

```
│   db.sqlite3
│   manage.py
│
├───myapp
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │       __init__.py
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           urls.cpython-39.pyc
│           views.cpython-39.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│
├───static
│   └───myapp
│       └───css
│               index.css
│
├───templates
│       index.html
│       result.html
│
└───myapp
    │   asgi.py
    │   settings.py
    │   urls.py
    │   wsgi.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    └───__pycache__
        ...
```

Comment: please add url file

Comment: try to change : views.save to app.views.save

Comment: if it doesnt works , please share the project structure

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index , name='index'),
    path('save', views.save , name='save'),]
```

Try   :

```
  urlpatterns = [
        path('', myapp.views.index , name='index'),
        path('save',myapp.views.save , name='save')
```

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't work. The urls work bc I get redirected correct. So the error must be within the views.py or the ajax code, I think

Comment: When you put a break point you get to the function?

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean by a "break point"?

Comment: When you debug your code, you can put breakpoint in order to understand where you code fails